# Preferring exact match results in ElasticSearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search

We have a query on business names which is selecting inexact matches as better than exact matches.

For example, for the following (pseudo) query:

```
    curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/$ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX/company/_search" -d '
    {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "company_name": "ACME WIDGETS LLC"
        }
      }
    }
    '
```

Results:

- "ACME WIDGETS BUSINESS LLC" (score: 7.8596606)
- "ACME WIDGETS LLC" (score: 7.7698755)  (should be top result)

We have attempted phrase matching, but this is too strict. We looked at the constant_score wrapper, but this eliminates the scoring, which we do need.

I don't believe the mapping affects the query in this case, but can supply if required.

Any suggestions for how to get the behaviour we want? Should we be considering different query types?

Using the explain functionality indicates that the documents are analysed in the same way; the slightly different scores I believe occur because they are on different shards. What I don't understand is how to penalise a document with an extraneous word in the search.

Comment: try to use `match_phrase` instead of `match`, what do you get?

Comment: I suggest a `bool` query that uses multiple `should` statements. One of these statements is an exact match. What exact means depends on what you need. The simplest approach is to define a `.raw` subfield for that  `company_name` field and make it `not_analyzed` or analyzed with `keyword`. Then one of your `should` statements would be a `term` query for `company_name.raw`. If it matches it will add to the overall score a value, if not, the score of the document will be the one of the `match` statement only.

Comment: I can provide a sample query and mapping if you are interested in this approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "(pseudo) query"?  If this isn't a query you've actually run, might be worth seeing something that is, to be sure it *actually* demonstrates the issue.  At any rate, though, try using [Explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-explain.html) if you are having trouble understanding why documents are scored a certain way.

Comment: It's the exact query other than I've changed the actual search terms to generalise them rather than make it very specific to our internal system.

Comment: @AndreiStefan, your approach is interesting. It seems though quite complicated to achieve this - is there no option to penalise based on the extra word?

Comment: Elasticsearch is both by structuring the data being indexed in a specific and useful way and about the query itself. Is not always about the query. These two work hand in hand.

Comment: And is not complicated, it's just another approach of controlling the scoring.

Answer (score 1):

In That case you can probably try this .
This will give high score to exact match but will match a query with little deviation as well.

Let me know your outcome with this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "company_name": {
              "query": "ACME WIDGETS LLC",
              "slop": 5,
              "boost": 5
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "company_name": {
              "query": "ACME WIDGETS LLC",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try match_phrase with slop as below:

```
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/$ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX/company/_search" -d '
{
  "query": {
      "match_phrase": {
          "company_name": {
             "query": "ACME WIDGETS LLC",
             "slop":  5
        }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Comment: Thank you; the problem with this is that then any slight deviation from the exact phrase will cause no results at all to be returned. For example, querying for: "ACME WIDGET LLC" will not match.